# How to get just str values into csv using DictWriter with multiple values per row

Tags: python, csv

I've generated a dict of dicts, each containing 5 randomly generated string elements.

I'm trying to output each dict into a single row in a csv file, with just the "clean" string value, without quotes or brackets.

Starting with this:

```
numberofhands = range(int(raw_input("# of hands you want to generate: ")))

allhands = {} #create a place for all the hand dicts to go

for i in numberofhands: # loads allhands with specified # of 5 card hands
temphand = makehand(battlepile)
allhands.update({i:temphand})

with open(nameoffile,'wb') as outfile: #makes csv using writer and list of dict values
writer = csv.writer(outfile,delimiter='\t')
for key, value in allhands.items():
    aRow = []
    for i in value:
        aRow.append(value[i])
    writer.writerow([aRow])
```

The output looks like this:

> ['Spider' 'Spaceship' 'Evil' 'Porcupine' 'Sword']
>
> ['Train' 'Sumo Wrestler' 'Saw' 'Glass' 'Robot']
>
> ['Bees'   'Cannon' 'House' 'T.N.T' 'Sumo Wrestler']
>
> ['Air' 'Spider' 'Wind' 'Spaceship' 'spicy']
>
> ['Turtle' 'Santa Claus' 'Car' 'Airplane' 'Cloud']

My goal is to get output that looks like this:

> Spider Spaceship Evil Porcupine Sword
>
> Train Sumo Wrestler Saw Glass Robot
>
> Bees Cannon House T.N.T Sumo Wrestler
>
> Air Spider Wind Spaceship spicy
>
> Turtle Santa Claus Car Airplane Cloud

I'm struggling with DictWriter - is there a cleaner, pythonic way to achieve this? Here's where I am currently:

```
with open(nameoffile, 'wb') as outfile: #makes csv using DictWriter and list of dict values
fieldnames = [1,2,3,4,5]
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, dialect='excel', fieldnames=fieldnames)
for key, value in allhands.items():
    writer.writeheader()
    for k, v in value[key]:
        writer.writerow([v])
```

Which gives `KeyError: 0`

I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Here a example how to write from a Dict to a CSV file via DictWriter.

I hoop it helps.

```
import csv
allhands = {1:'Spider', 2:'Spaceship', 3:'Evil', 4:'Porcupine', 5:'Sword'}          

nameoffile ='E://file.csv'
with open(nameoffile, 'wb') as outfile:
    #makes csv using DictWriter
    fieldnames = [1,2,3,4,5]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, dialect='excel', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()    
    temp = dict()
    for keys, values in allhands.items():
        temp[keys] = values
    writer.writerow(temp)
```

Comment: Thanks! From your example, it looks like the missing step was creating a list from the dict values, then just writewrow that list. I don't quite understand what temp = dict() is doing though - I never defined dict(). Is that a tuple?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sadegh, I got it to work, but I don't quite understand why :)

The part that's confusing to me is:

```
temp = dict()
for keys, values in allhands.items():
    temp[keys] = values
writer.writerow(temp)
```

I never defined dict(), and is that creating a tuple?

My functioning code is below - I just stuck this answer into a for loop iterating over my dict of dicts.

```
with open(nameoffile, 'wb') as outfile: #makes csv using DictWriter and list of dict values
for k, v in allhands.items():
    fieldnames = [1,2,3,4,5]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, dialect='excel', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    temp = dict()
    for keys, values in v.items():
        temp[keys] = values
    writer.writerow(temp)
```

2nd question: Is it pythonic to re-initiate writer inside the for loop? I had assumed that this was going to return a single line in a csv file, having overwritten itself, and ending with the contents of the last dict.

But it works! Just wish I understood why :)